# Hide/Show body background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a new website, i'm using a background image rotaror (after refresh).
I made a switch where you can turn on/off the background image.

I found some scripts that can do it with div's but not with the body in css.
So when the on/off switch is click i need to get "background:" removed.

Can somebody help me out with a jquery/javascript script?

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("../img/landingpage/background/random.php") fixed no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: white;
font-family: verdana;
}
```

Comment: save the `url(".......") fixed no-repeat` to a var... then you can do:   `$item.css("background", mrVar)` and `$item.css("background","");`

Comment: Maybe something like `background-image: none;`?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('body').css('background' : '');
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work: jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/607

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#switch").on("click", function () {
    $("body").css("background", "none");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! is it also possible when unchecking the button you get the background back?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work now, with the toggle function

```
$("#myonoffswitch").toggle( 
function (){
    $("body").css("background", "none");
}
,
function (){
    $("body").css("background", "url('http://p1.pichost.me/640/27/1502004.jpg')"); 
}
);
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/A97G3/